# Splitting an NSString into seperate strings based on different delimiters

Tags: ios, nsarray

Example string:

```
NSString * exampleString = 
@""
 "#--- delimiter2 ---"
 "bla,"
 "bla,"
 "bla"
 "#--- delimiter2 ---"
 "yoip,"
 "yoip,"
 "yoip"
 "#--- delimiter3 ---"
 "etc,"
 "etc,"
 "etc,"
 "etc,"
 "etc,"
 "etc,"
 "etc";
```

I want to take an array and populate it as:

```
[anyArray objectAtIndex:0] = @"bla,bla,bla"

[anyArray objectAtIndex:1] = @"yoip,yoip,yoip"

[anyArray objectAtIndex:2] = @"etc,etc,etc,etc,etc,etc,etc"
```

If that makes sense...

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
NSArray *spliArray = [exampleString componentsSeparatedByString:@"delimiter"];
```

Comment: then I have "#-- " as one of the elements in the spliArray...however I did figure out what I had to do.

Comment: @NathanielRogers can you let me know what you figured out?